# Alter table convert to using latin1

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I need to do what I do here for a whole table:

```
UPDATE users SET name = CONVERT(CAST(convert(name using  latin1) as BINARY) USING utf8);
```

How do I do this with the ALTER TABLE query ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say columnA is defined as VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 then you can change it to utf8 so that it can have different values from different languages using below:

```
  ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY columnA VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Are you looking at my CAST - cause i'm converting two times ?

Comment: when you convert it to BINARY it will have 0x00 at the end so it does not look good; Btw, how is your column `name` defined? I assumed it to be CHAR; isn't?

Comment: Char is varchar for name. But i have the issue throughout the table.

Comment: if it is varchar then the conversion is much trivial. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that is the correct fix.

If I am not mistaken, you are trying to undo "double-encoding"?

See this for symptoms:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

See this for where the fix applies:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases
Namely

CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 with double-encoding:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(col USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);
```

Dump the table, load it somewhere else, run the conversion, test the results, especially getting `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`